# Working with plain vi not vim

Tags: command-line, server, vi

I was trying to learn working with vi, the plain 'vi' that ships with most of the operating system, but that 'vi' seems to be missing lot of features.
When I tried to excute ":ls", it gave me error `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version.`

Similarly for most of commands, When I tried `:version`, it returned `Small version without GUI` .

For now I just want to learn working with "vi" not "vim".

- So any nice place where I can learn from(I found most tutorials are for vim).
- Any easy ways to extend functionality of "vi" not "vim"
- Any tips if I'm going on wrong path

Comment: and when tried to load 5 files in "vi", they were not even working, ":bn" was also not available, any pointer on that . !

Comment: Mind to share where you got the plain vi? I know there exist nvi , elvis and some other clones,  but which one you are using,? And where can I get it too?

Comment: I'm using the one which come with OS, and I'm using wheezy !
No extra "sudo apt-get install vim"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "vi" command that comes with Ubuntu is actually just linked to **vim**, with options that disable several of its features, putting it in a sort of "vi compatibility mode", the same as using the `:set compatible` command.

The original "vi" itself is ancient, and has a license that would not allow it to be distributed with Ubuntu.  It has a number of spiritual successors in the form of open source editors that emulate it, but the most popular of these is vim, followed by nvi and elvis.

- **vim** is the most popular successor to vi, and adds many helpful features, many which you are used to and probably think of as being part of vi, but in reality are features added to vim.  vim aims for improved usability.
- **nvi** is another editor that attempts to more closely emulate the original vi, but has since gone on to add many improvements.
- **elvis** is another editor that attempts to closely emulate the original vi but add extra features.  elvis is the vi-like editor used by Slackware Linux.
- **busybox** is a multi-purpose executable that includes a vi-like editor, but also includes a number of other command line tools.  It is designed for embedded systems and devices with very low memory or storage space.  Its vi-like editor is a vi clone optimised for very low size and memory use.
- **neovim** is a fork of vim intended to implement some features vim is seen to lack.  It was once heralded as the new vim replacement but its growth has been slower than some hoped during initial enthusiasm about the project.

The reasons you're having problems is that you're trying to use vim commands in vim's "vi compatibility mode" which disables these features.

I don't see any value in limiting yourself to just the commands that were in the original vi, as that editor is not really relevant anymore and you may as well benefit from the increased usability and functionality of vim or one of the other clones.

Comment: I was trying to learn editor which is working with all OS, without and extra download .!
So I thought plain "vi" will be a good choice

Comment: vim is relatively universal these days, but yes, you can get pretty close to plain vi by using vim in compatible mode (which "vi" does by default in Ubuntu") or busybox vi.

Comment: I installed wheezy, but it wasn't there, but no probs 
I got few shortcuts like ":n" , ":args" intead of ":ls" and now I can use ":!command", that will take care of my problems, and I'll keep on exploring ..
Thanx for your answer . !

Answer (score 4):

Five years after putting this question, I use `vim` as my daily driver. 
It doesn't matter vi/vim, you need to used to binding, and vim-style of working. I wanted to work on system and see how things work, vim has really been helpful for me.

As @thomasrutter said

> I don't see any value in limiting yourself to just the commands that were in the original vi, as that editor is not really relevant anymore and you may as well benefit from the increased usability and functionality of vim or one of the other clones.

If someone else is reading it, `tmux` is one tool that I use along with vim now, which makes all my workflow.

If you get want more automation `tmuxinator` would be next tool to be. For starters use `tmux` with `vim` and then see it it's suits you and move ahead.

Comment: Just saw this now. I'm happy to see your update 5 years on